# MySQL - Percentage increase based on multiple columns not working

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I am trying to write a query that calculates the percentage increase based on three columns A1, A2, A3. The objective is to determine the percentage increase/decrease. Please see the simplified Excel calculations

[image]

Here A1, A2, A3 are three columns in my table `PCLS` using which I am updating the table `PCNT`. The calculation is straightforward, I first count the number of times PCNT.`A` appears in columns A1, A2, A3 (4,52,3 in this case) then apply a factor of 10000 to get the initial value in column S10K. The column CV fetches the current value from another source, now my objective is to determine the % increase or decrease of CV versus S10K. In the Excel example, it would be (630135.6-590000)/(590000)*100 corresponding to a 6.80% increase. It seems straight forward in Excel but I am unable to get it to calculate correctly in MySQL. I tried the following

```
UPDATE PCNT SET `R%`= (
    (
        (
            (
                (SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`) 
                + (SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A2`=PCNT.`A`) 
                + (SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A3`=PCNT.`A`)
            ) 
            - (
                (
                    (SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`)
                    + (SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A2`=PCNT.`A`)
                    + (SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A3`=PCNT.`A`)
                )*10000
            )
        )
    ) 
    / 
    (
        (
            (SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`)
            + (SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A2`=PCNT.`A`)
            + (SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A3`=PCNT.`A`)
        ) * 10000
    )
)*100;
```

However, this seems to only work when PCNT.`A` is present in all the three columns A1, A2, A3. If it is not present in either of the columns it evaluates to NULL.

I tried the following alternative, but the problems does not go away

```
UPDATE PCNT
set `R%` = ((((((SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`) - ((SELECT 
count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))/((SELECT count(`CV`) from 
PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))*100))) + ((((((SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS 
WHERE `A2`=PCNT.`A`) - ((SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE 
`A2`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))/((SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE 
`A2`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))*100))) + ((((((SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE 
`A3`=PCNT.`A`) - ((SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE 
`A3`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))/((SELECT count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE 
`A3`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))*100)));
```

If I use the below query, limiting the search to just column A1, everything seems to work fine. This query evaluates to 16.34% similar to what can be seen in the Excel screenshot.

```
UPDATE PCNT
set `R%` = (((SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`) - ((SELECT 
count(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))/((SELECT count(`CV`) from 
PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`)*10000))*100;
```

The moment, I include A2 and A3 any values of PCNT.`A` that are not present in A1, A2 evaluate to NULL. All I want is the query to return (630135.6-590000)/(590000)*100 = 6.80% but I am having a hard time getting it to work. I feel that the addition operation causes the problem.

Is there a correct or alternate way of doing this. I have tried making multiple changes but have not been successful.

```
SELECT SUM(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`
SELECT COUNT(`CV`) from PCLS WHERE `A1`=PCNT.`A`
```

The above two queries, if run standalone seem to work fine, the problem starts when I use the addition operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The moment, I include A2 and A3 any values of PCNT.A that are not present in A1, A2 evaluate to NULL. [...] I feel that the addition operation causes the problem.

An addition where one of the members is `NULL` returns `NULL` (same goes for other arithmetic operations). You would need to wrap the subqueries  with `COALESCE()`, to returns `0` instead.

Bottom line, I do suspect that your query could be rewritten to replace the multiples inline queries with `LEFT JOIN`s on aggregated subqueries, like:

```
UPDATE pcnt pn
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a1, SUM(cv) sumcv, COUNT(cv) cntcv FROM pcls GROUP BY a1) pa1 ON pa1.a1 = pn.a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a2, SUM(cv) sumcv, COUNT(cv) cntcv FROM pcls GROUP BY a2) pa2 ON pa2.a2 = pn.a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a3, SUM(cv) sumcv, COUNT(cv) cntcv FROM pcls GROUP BY a3) pa3 ON pa3.a3 = pn.a
SET pn.`R%` = 
    ( 
        COALESCE(pa1.sumcv, 0) + COALESCE(pa2.sumcv, 0) + COALESCE(pa3.sumcv, 0)
        - (COALESCE(pa1.cntcv, 0) + COALESCE(pa2.cntcv, 0) + COALESCE(pa3.cntcv, 0)) * 10000
    ) 
    / ((COALESCE(pa1.cntcv, 0) + COALESCE(pa2.cntcv, 0) + COALESCE(pa3.cntcv, 0)) * 10000)
    * 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMB. I appreciate your help and tip. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: Welcome @Quark!

Comment: I realized that your query executes in seconds, while my original update query (leaving aside the fact that it did not accomplish its intended goal) took several minutes.